# How do I copy and paste a pattern of a few cells in a column down the whole column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with the first top-six cells as:

1. column D1: Total days worked
2. column D2: (formula for total days worked)
3. column D3: empty cell
4. column d4: Total Hours Worked
5. column d5: (formula for total hours worked)
6. column d6: empty cell

how do I copy these first six cells in the column and repeat them vertically over the rest of column D?

I can drag the bottom right corner to copy and paste them, but I want it to repeat forever instead of just the number of cells I can vertically scroll down to with my mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I just selected the six cells in the column, selected 'copy', then selected the entire column by hitting the column letter at the top, then selected 'paste'. worked.